# Str split and explode

Tags: python, pandas, string

How could I string split and explode whilst retaining information?

```
df
0   Apple_a red, green; banana_b yellow
1   peach_p orange; pear_p green
```

Expected output

```
0 Apple_a red
1 Apple_a green
2 banana_b yellow
3 peach_p orange
4 pear_p green
```

I tried:

```
df1 =df.str.split("; ").str.split(" ", n=1)
df2=df1.str[0] +x for x in df1.str[1:]
df2.explode()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
data = ['Apple_a red, green; banana_b yellow', 'peach_p orange; pear_p green']
s1 = pd.Series(data)
```

output(`s1`):

```
0    Apple_a red, green; banana_b yellow
1           peach_p orange; pear_p green
dtype: object
```

**My idea**

```
s1.str.split('; ').explode().str.split(r',* ', expand=True)
```

output:

```
    0           1       2
0   Apple_a     red     green
0   banana_b    yellow  None
1   peach_p     orange  None
1   pear_p      green   None
```

On my idea using `set_index`, `stack`, `reset_index` and so on, get your `desired output`.

```
(s1.str.split('; ').explode().str.split(r',* ', expand=True)
 .set_index(0).stack().to_frame(2).reset_index(0)
 .apply(' '.join, axis=1)
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

result:

```
0        Apple_a red
1      Apple_a green
2    banana_b yellow
3     peach_p orange
4       pear_p green
dtype: object
```

code is longer using `stack` instead of `melt`, because of sort order. If you don't care about the sort order, you can use `melt` instead `stack`.